# How to catch an exception of Interbase on Connect when gdb file doesn't exist on a given path

Tags: database, c++builder, interbase, fibplus

I have fib+ comps installed on my machine and 
trying to catch Interbase exception on connecting but one exception I cannot catch

```
try {
        DM->dBase->Connected=false;
        DM->dBase->DBName=DBPATH;
        DM->dBase->Connected=true;
    } catch (Exception &e) {
        ShowMessage("Exception "+ (AnsiString(e.Message)));
    }
```

if i change the DBPATH to a non-existent gdb file it throws an exception like

**Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful exection of subsequent statements. I/O error for file .Error while trying to open file**

Is it possible to catch this exception????
I debugged my code but cursor didn't come till try catch exception block and before that my aforementioned exception comes on!!!

If yes how can i catch this kind of exception????

Answer (score 3):

Could it be that the exception is not inherited from the base exception class `Exception`, if so have you tried adding a `catch(...)` as well?

I'm not sure I understand your post entirely, but is it possible that what you see is not, that your program isn't catching the exception. It is that the debugger presents it to you before it is being handled by your catch statement? If this is the case then you can tell the debugger to not present this exception type for you.

Does the exception arrive if you run the program outside the debugger?

Comment: Yes, it does when I run my application, as well!

Comment: +1 I bet the exception "comes" outside the debugger because OP is calling ShowMessage in the exception handler.